# Vuetify badges not fully visible on Snackbar

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm not sure why this is happening, and hope there is a css wizard out here who can point me in the right direction.

I created a control in a Vue (3.3.4) app with Vuetify (3.3.21) that uses a Snackbar and Badges.  It works as expected.

[image]

I am now attempting to use the same control in an existing Vue (3.3.4) application using the same version of Vuetify (3.3.21), however the badges are cut off at the edge of the Snackbar.

[image]

I know this isn't much to go on, but I can't recreate this issue, and can't post the code.  I'm just hoping that someone can point me in the right direction.

I have compared both using Chrome devtools and don't see a difference.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try opening your browser's dev tools and inspect the DOM.  It should reveal the exact differences in elements and/or CSS properties, then that should give you a clue for what code to track down and change.

Comment: @yoduh - thanks for the comment.  However I have compared both using the dev tools and can't seem to find a difference.  I'm hoping that someone might know what causes this behavior so I can look for that, but as of now I don't see a difference.

Comment: There must still be some stylesheet unique to one of them causing a difference. Check all global CSS/stylesheets since they can affect CSS from anywhere in the app.  There couldn't be a visual difference if the code were actually exactly the same.  Failing that, I would fiddle around in the inspector regardless and work out what CSS properties/values need to change to make the badges not be cut off.  Without any code it's impossible to tell what invisible parent or container elements might be involved.  Maybe a container height or overflow property that needs to change.

Comment: @yoduh - Thanks for the help, it's appreciated.  You're right, there has to be some difference in the css, but I couldn't find it.  However I did find the issue.  I was using a different version of Vuetify and didn't realize it.  It looks like there is a bug in Vuetify 3.4.x that causes this.  3.3.x works fine.  I was actually able to reproduce the bug with new code using Vuetify 3.4.0.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't using the same version of Vuetify in both projects. The one with the issue was using the newest version (3.4.9) and the other was 3.3.21.  It looks like there is a bug in Vuetify 3.4.x that causes this.  I just downgraded to 3.3.x for now, and will submit a bug for Vuetify.